# C++11 regex to match $VARNAME or ${VARNAME}

Tags: regex, c++11

need a C++11 regex to match:

```
"$VARNAME" or "${VARNAME}"
```

Where VARNAME can be any alphanumeric literal.

Here's what I tried:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void main() {       
    string line = "${USERPROFILE}/blah/blah/blah";
    smatch M;

    regex   r1{ R"(\$\{?(\w+)\}?)" };
    bool success = regex_match(line, M, r1); 
    if (!success) {
        cout << "Why doesn't this match?" << endl;
    }
    return;
}
```

Why doesn't this match?

Comment: `\${?[a-zA-Z0-9]+}?`

Comment: your pattern should be fine

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/regex/ECMAScript/

Comment: try in visual studio 2015...doesn't match

Comment: the part that kind of throws me is that cplusplus references says: 
"Any character can be escaped except those which form any of the special character sequences above: such as ( [ {, etc..."  hrm?

Comment: after looking at regex_match (I'm not that familiar with regex in cpp), it looks like you should try `if(regex_match(line, r1))`. The format is `regex_match(matchstring, pattern)`. The rest is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because your pattern doesn't `match` your test string. instead of `std::regex_match` you need `std::regex_search`

Comment: ohh...that's a good point!   "regex_match only returns true when the entire input sequence has been matched, while regex_search will succeed even if only a sub-sequence matches the regex. "